# Is the time complexity different for storing attributes of nodes in an array vs. creating instances of a class to store it?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am building a `binary search tree` from an input `array of integers`. But I also want to store the size of the left subtree for each node as I am building the `BST`.

There were two ways that I thought of storing this number, either in an `array` (of the same size as the input array), or as an instance of the `BST initialisation`.

From a `space complexity` stand point, is there any difference? I would think that the space complexity of the array method would be O(n), but if we stored the size for every node as an instance of a class, I would think this results in O(1) space?- just for storing the size of the left subtree. Because I know that constructing the BST would be O(n) anyway for space, since the BST would be the same size of the input array?

For example:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value
        self.sizeOfLeftSubtree = 0
        self.parentPointer = None
```

Comment: How could it ever be possible to store n numbers in O(1) space? Or if you mean space *per number*, then why would an array be O(n)?

Comment: kaya, I mean storing the size of left subtree in the BST initialisation, would this take O(n) too?

Comment: What do you mean by storing something in the initialisation? Initialisation is a thing the program does, not a place. Perhaps you should write the two ways you are thinking about in actual code.

Comment: I have added to my question above. What I meant is that say for every node/integer in the array I have a sizeOfLeftSubtree, will this take O(n) space?

Comment: It will take O(n) space in total for the whole tree, if the tree has n nodes. For reference, this isn't "storing it in the initialisation", it's storing it as an attribute of the node.

Comment: Great thank you Kaya, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of space complexity. In either case you are allocating memory for *n* integers. Either as an array of *n* integers, or as one more integer **in each** of the *n* nodes.

Some remarks:

- If you choose to store it as an array, then you have to deal with two data structures: the tree and the array. And when in a certain algorithm you have a *current* node, you'll have to know which *index* in that array corresponds to it. This is not the OOP way to do it. In OOP one makes sure that all data that relates to a specific entity, is stored together with that entity as an object.
- *"as an instance of the BST initialisation"* mixes two concepts: an instance of the `BST` class is an object. Initialisation is (in this context) the process of assigning values to an object's attributes. Your code indicates that an instance gets an additional *attribute* during its initialisation. It is a matter of using the right terminology.